# Attach to current process on nodejs over ubuntu server terminal

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, terminal

I have a process running over a ubuntu server. I only have access on terminal.

I made this script:

index.js

```
let i = 0;

setInterval( () => {
        i++;
        console.log(`try ${i}`);
}, 1000);
```

I run with: node index.js &

Now I open a new terminal and I want to see the result on console.log.

How can I do it?

New edit:

The principal idea is send a console.log in a terminal and, recovery this console.log in another terminal. This is the goal. Recovery the console log in another terminal. How can I do it?

Comment: If you just want to see the console.log, why don't you just direct the output to a file and open it in a new terminal?

Comment: because this is a simple example for the real problem, the process is running on a server and I cant kill the process and restart, then I need to attach to this process on another terminal

Comment: One other thing that sprang to my mind is that you may want to do that:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/how-do-i-attach-a-terminal-to-a-detached-process

Comment: if your problem is not solved, leave a comment

Comment: No solved Mohammad

Answer (score -1):

Of top of my head, I'd suggest going for a combination of https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander and some sort of IPC - `redis`-based,`*mq` or plain https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ipc

If you don't have wide variety of commands you'd need to send to that process, you can also get away using signals, for example: `SIGUSR1`, `SIGUSR2`.

Comment: I am tring this links, but I still witout can do.

Comment: You'll have to update your question and show what exactly you are doing, otherwise it's hard to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Look, open a terminal and run: node index.js & (this is the scrip on top)

Then, I open a new terminal (another) and I want to see the result on console.log of the first terminal. How can I do it?

Comment: Well, show your code. You said you've been trying the links with no success.

Comment: let i = 0;

setInterval( () => {
        i++;
        console.log(`try ${i}`);
}, 1000);

Comment: glock18. Look, if you have nodejs, please run the principal code in a terminal. When the script is running, please, open another terminal. In the new terminal, how do you do for get the console.log print of the main terminal.

Comment: @gabrielrincon, yes I have node.js. You'll have to pick one of the two. First, you tell me that console.log is just a simplified version of something more intricate that you want to do without any specificity. Then you tell me that that's exactly what you want to do. If the latter is the case, I'll go back to my original recommendation - direct your output to a file and open this file in your new terminal. For more intricate stuff, post how exactly you've been trying to use modules I mentioned in the answer. I'm afraid, if you won't be cooperative in helping yourself, you won't get any help.

Comment: ok, understand, look, I put some console.logs, please ignore me my comment for the real problem because this is a complex app. The principal idea is send a console.log in a terminal and, recovery this console.log in another terminal. I'm sorry for the confusion. This is the goal. Recovery the console log in another terminal

Comment: I see, please take a look at the comment I placed to the question. Perhaps, it's what you've been looking for in the end. I'm not sure though, that it'll allow you to restore past output, but it's where I'd start searching from.